# Highschool Probability: Chances of player winning

Tags: probability

[image]

I tried finding the probability of getting a W which turned out to be 1/2 and then multiplied it by the probability of getting a number greater than 1. However my answer turned out to be 0.3, if you look at the question carefully it says "Give your answer correct to two decimal places." and my answer is only correct to one.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A decimal number can have any number of zeroes behind the last number and still not change. Thus, you can write 0.30 and still be as correct as if you had said 0.3.